# Node/Express: Adding middleware to router does not load

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

My router looks like this:

```
app.get('/getReport', (req, res) => {
    res.send("This is the report");
});
```

The above router works fine and the browser loads, `This is the report`

but when I do this:

```
// Filename: router.js

const getReport = require('./getReportController');

app.get('/getReport', (req, res) => {
    getReport.initial
});
```

and

```
// Filename: getReportController.js

exports.initial = (req, res) => {
    res.send("This is the report");
};
```

It does not work and keep waiting...

What could have gone wrong? My goal is to call the controller components, and then add it to the router end point. There is going to be `middleware` which I will add once this is resolved.

Comment: `app.get('/getReport', (req, res) => getReport.initial(req,res));` does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is:

```
app.get('/getReport', getReport.initial);
```

You're just reading the function within a function block the way you're doing it.